# UTF encoding for http post using okhttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to post some data to a web server using OkHttp

```
public static void sendNewPost(NewPost post, Context context) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException{

    RequestBody body = post.buildBody();
    URL url = buildURL("newreply.php");
    openPage(url, body, context);
}


public class NewPost {
    ...

    public setMessage(String m) {
        MESSAGE = "Probando con la letra: ñ, áéíóú";
    }

    public RequestBody buildBody() throws NoSuchFieldException{
        ...
        RequestBody postVariables = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add(MESSAGE_KEY, MESSAGE)
            .build();
        return postVariables;


    }

}
```

If I send that, the server will show something like this:

```
Probando con la letra: Ã±, Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº
```

However If I change the setMessage function:

```
public setMessage(String m) {

    m = "Probando con la letra: ñ, áéíóú";
    MESSAGE = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {
        switch (m.charAt(i)) {
            case 'ñ':
                MESSAGE += "%u00F1";
                break;
            case 'á':
                MESSAGE += "%u00E1";
                break;
            case 'é':
                MESSAGE += "%u00E9";
                break;
            case 'í':
                MESSAGE += "%u00ED";
                break;
            case 'ó':
                MESSAGE += "%u00F3";
                break;
            case 'ú':
                MESSAGE += "%u00FA";
                break;
            default:
                MESSAGE += m.charAt(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Things works as expected and the server shows the right thing. I reckon it is replacing the spanish characters for their UTF-16 codes, but I wonder if there is a better way to encode the full string, or make OkHttp handle it.

Edit: When I log the network traffic I see that, if my message is: "ññ" the browser encodes it as:

```
...&message=%F1%F1&...
```

while when I do it on android & okhttp, the message is sent as:

```
...&message=%C3%B1%C3%B1&...
```

Thats the thing I want, how to make OkHttp encode the string like the browser does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of solutions that I know of:

1. [PapaParse](http://PapaParse.com) at https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse

   - Pros: It's really lightweight
   - Cons: Don't know of any, it's always done the job for me
2. Or, if you're already using guava or willing to take on the extra app size/method count, it has a thorough selection of parsers/delimiters/URL escapers [as described in the javadoc here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html)

   - Pros: It's got everything you could ever need for special char parsing
   - Cons: guava rarely considered useful enough in its own right to justify the extra method count it brings

Comment: The thing is I prefer to understand what the browser is doing and then set the encoding accordingly, instead of doing it "manually", I have added some more info to the main post.